# CSS hyphenate issues with longer words in Chrome

Tags: html, css, hyphenation, css-hyphens

I am trying to use CSS hyphens to hyphenate long words, such as in
[this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZjEP.png)

As you can see the last letter drops on the new line. This happens in Chrome, not for example in Safari. As my layout is using blocks of certain width and I would like to fit the words into blocks, the solution is not to change the font-size or block width, but rather to solve the hyphenate issue.

```css
p {
  width: 105px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

p.hyphenate {
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p class="hyphenate">ANONYMOUSLY</p>
<p class="hyphenate">EXEMPLARITY</p>
<p class="hyphenate">THAT EXEMPLARITY</p>
```

In the last paragraph "Y" drops on the new line without any hyphenation.

Here is the CodePen example. Works fine in Safari, does not work in Chrome:

```
https://codepen.io/jospo/pen/MWWjzLe
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyphens` is only a **Working Draft** CSS property at present and currently is not fully implemented or supported by all browsers.

I suggest you review the support tables at [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens) which has the following notes.

> Chrome < 55 and Android 4.0 Browser support "-webkit-hyphens: none", but not the "auto" property. It is advisable to set the @lang attribute on the HTML element to enable hyphenation support and improve accessibility.
>
> For Chrome: **Only supported on Android & Mac platforms** (and only the "auto" value) for now.

Comment: Thanks Paulie. I am testing this on Mac where the "auto" value should be supported, but for this specific example it does not work properly. It is possible the ```hyphens``` implementation in Chrome for Mac and Android is still somehow broken.